# How do I get HQL to join on the correct field in this scenario?

Tags: left-join, hql, orchardcms

I am developing a solution based on the Orchard CMS (1.7.1) and am writing the solution in C#.

I have two tables which use a common base class.
The ProductRecord has a list of zero or more PLUs.

```
public class ModelBaseClass
{
    public abstract int Id {get;set;}
}

public class ProductRecord : ModelBaseClass
{
    [Key]
    public override int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual ProductRecord MasterProductRecord {get;set;}
    public virtual IList<PLURecord> PLUs {get;set;}
}

public class PLURecord
{
    [Key]
    public override int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual ProductRecord ProductRecord {get;set;}
}
```

I then want to get all the products with their associated PLUs as a left join using HQL.

My HQL is...

```
select product.Id, product.Name, plu.Id
from XYZ.Models.ProductRecord as product
left join product.PLUs as plu
```

The HQL is getting confused by the presence of the MasterProductRecord and producing a query which will not execute ...

```
could not execute query 
[ select TOP (@p0) productrec0_.Id as col_0_0_, productrec0_.Name as col_1_0_, plus1_.Id as col_2_0_ from PROJ_XYZ_StockControl_ProductRecord productrec0_ left outer join PROJ_XYZ_StockControl_PLURecord plus1_ on productrec0_.Id=plus1_.MasterProductRecord_id ] 
[SQL: select TOP (@p0) productrec0_.Id as col_0_0_, productrec0_.Name as col_1_0_, plus1_.Id as col_2_0_ from PROJ_XYZ_StockControl_ProductRecord productrec0_ left outer join PROJ_XYZ_StockControl_PLURecord plus1_ on productrec0_.Id=plus1_.MasterProductRecord_id]

Invalid column name 'MasterProductRecord_id'.
```

The SQL will work if it references the field ProductRecord_id and not MasterProductRecord_id

So, is there some way to tell the model that the id field should be used for the join or to ignore the MasterProductRecord on joins? 
Or is there a more precise way to specify the join in HQL?

**EDIT: I added in info on the C# Base class which is where the actual Id field is defined.  It is then overridden in the model class.  This may be relevant?

Comment: Are you sure this is the SQL for that HQL? I'm confused about where that QuickDeliveryRecord table is coming from.

Comment: Bertrand, I errantly copied in the wrong error text.  I have edited the question to correct this.

Comment: It looks like the problem is in the mapping of the PLUs list on ProductRecord. Can you show that mapping?

Comment: This is being developed within the Orchard CMS. As far as I can tell, Orchard CMS hides the mappings and these are then handled by following conventions.  I dont believe that I have any further control over the mappings within nHibernate - the mappings are not exposed further. There may be some additional C# attributes I can add to properties to advise nHibernate.  I think you are right though, as far as I can tell, if I did not have the MasterProductRecord property, this would all work as is.

Comment: Try to rename that property to ProductRecord, as an experiment.

Comment: My C# compiler doesnt like that idea! "Error 'ProductRecord': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type"